# Cake PHP => Combine conditions array and SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

how can I combine a conditions array and a normal SQL statement?
My conditions array looks like the following one:

```
[conditions] => Array
    (
        [AND] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Webdetail.kW1 LIKE] => %%
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Webdetail.Upm1 LIKE] => %%
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [Webdetail.Volt1 LIKE] => %%
                    )
```

But in some cases I have to use a normal SQL statement for the Webdetail.Upm1 field, instead the LIKE.
The SQL statement looks like:  between 500*.9 and 500*1.1 and pol1=12

Thank you,
Nico

Comment: Check this - > http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your conditions:

```
'Webdetail.Upm1 BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(500 * 0.9, 500 * 1.1)
```